# video (autoplay) gets hidden via javascript but already starts on pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe, embed

i wanted to find a simple method to get a custom preview-image to my videos within my blog by hiding them and make them visible right after click on the preview-image. the user Dominic Green helped me to get it nearly started.

the problem is: the video already starts to play (even if it is hidden) in autoplay-mode right after the pageload (you can hear the sound in the background) but i want to have the autoplay to start right after click on the preview-image...

here's the example how i did it so far (click on the flower-images will make the video visible): http://brayaz.de/test/example.html

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the url in your YouTube embed code to "autoplay=0" instead of "autoplay=1".

So change

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you want the video to start right after clicking the thumbnail, you'll need some javascript.  If that is the case, see: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player

Comment: i setted the autoplay to "1" myself cause i want to have it in autoplay but (as you already mentioned) right AFTER the click on the thmubnail... i'm not really into javascript... i checked the link but i don't know what to do yet... do i have to add something to my current javascript?

Comment: ..and i forgot to say, that i don't want to have JUST youtube videos get played after click... i want EVERY embedded flash-data (iframe) start after click (vimeo, soundcloud, etc)....

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty complicated, as the APIs for different services (ie SoundCloud, Vimeo, YouTube) will behave differently.

The best solution I can come up with is to listen for a click event on the thumbnail, then test for the embedded media type, then send a 'play' API call based on the media type (ie SoundCloud audio, Vimeo video).

That solution would require javascript, however.  Perhaps someone smarter will find a different way round!